# Hyuntai Elantra 2013 - no engine crank, periodic full power failure

Tags: hyundai, elantra

When I try to start my Elantra I can hear the starter solenoid click, but the motor doesn't turn over / crank.

After a few attempts of this, the car loses all electrical power for awhile (~1 hour).  Turning the ignition to on doesn't display any dash lights, and none of the rest of the electrical systems work.  I've noticed that the dash lights also seem to fade on the last few attempts before everything goes dark.  After the hour I can use the electrical systems (turn on the lights, beep the horn, ect) until I try starting it again.

This happens with both the old and a new battery.

I'm planning to pull the starter motor, but it seems odd that it would affect the whole electrical system in this way.  I was wondering if anyone has any insights into what I'm seeing.

Comment: Check for broken or corroded battery cables.

Comment: Yep, this was it.  The threads and bolts from the battery's ground connection on the chassis needed to be cleaned.  Once that was done it started right up.
It probably wasn't a time based thing when it worked periodically, it's more likely that we were jostling the ground connection while we were working on the battery.

Comment: Good find, well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bad ground connection from the battery.  Tested the resistance from the battery ground to another ground point that connects to the transmission and it came out to ~10MΩ, after cleaning the threads and bolts on the battery ground connection it went down to ~0.9Ω.

[image]
[image]